# Lens name leads to "not found" error, but it exists

Tags: haskell

I have several modules. One of them defines a type `Xyz` and generates lens for it:

```hs
-- module A

data Xyz = Xyz {
  _xyzField :: Int
  , _xyzState :: SomeState
} (Generic, Show)

makeFields ''Xyz
```

and this module has another data-types with the same names like "state", "id" and so on.

Another one uses those fields:

```hs
-- module B
import qualified A

somefun :: A.Xyz -> ....
somefun xyz ... = do
  ...
  ... (xyz ^. A.field)  -- NO ERRORS HERE
  ... (xyz ^. A.state)  -- THERE IS AN ERROR HERE!
```

And I get an error `Not in scope A.state`. So, `state` name looks like magical name, but no problem with `field` one. What is the reason of the error and how to fix it? My suggestion was - shadowing of the name, but in this case I have to get another error message, like "already exists" or similar, so the reason is not "shadowing"...

If I rename the `state` to `stat` - the error is fixed. What is the reason of this?

Comment: It seems like lens imports `Control.Monad.Trans.State`, which has a function called `state`. I suspect that this has something to do with it.

Comment: so, the best fix is to rename the field (or to use `RecordWildCards`) ?